# How can we open a file for appending on perl?

Tags: database, perl

It will work like a database.

The example I want is:

**input :** `% perl youscript.pl Create_table mydb regtable REGION COUNTRY`

**output:**

```
mydb.txt(The contents of this file):

regtable

REGION|COUNTRY
```

and

**input :** `% perl youscript.pl Create_table mydb nametable SURNAME NAME`

**output:**

```
mydb.txt(The contents of this file):

regtable

REGION|COUNTRY


nametable

SURNAME|NAME
```

New entries should be added to each entry.

K. Rea: Thanks for all the help.

Comment: `print "$ARGV[1].txt\n$ARGV[2]\n$ARGV[3]|$ARGV[4]\n";`

Comment: Sorry, I said it would be written in the file. @PerlDuck

Comment: The question can be rephrased as _"How can we open a file for appending?"_

Comment: Thanks,Does this have a solution now?

Comment: Yes! You have a very well written answer now that not only shows the code you were asking for but also gives you a brief tutorial. Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Your example isn't really how a database works. It's just a flat file of variable-length records. If you wished to make it more efficient for lookups you would assure that record length is fixed, or would maintain a separate index of record offsets. But that's beyond the scope of answering your question.

It appears that the run semantics for the script are as follows:

```
myscript ACTION_NAME FILENAME CONTENT [CONTENT [...]]
```

Inside the script the fields passed on the command line will appear in the `@ARGV` array.

In the solution below I work with the assumption that you may want to eventually have other actions aside from `Create_table`, so an effort has been made to allow for extensibility.  A simple assumption will be that these actions operate on the parameters passed to `@ARGV` in some way. At least that's the case for `Create_table`.  So inside of `@ARGV` we will find the following:

```
@ARGV = ($action, $filename, @fields);
```

So first we set up a dispatch table that can handle various actions:

```
my %actions = (Create_table => sub {...}, ...);
```

Then we need is to shift off the action:

```
my $action = shift @ARGV;
```

And next we need to apply the dispatch:

```
if (exists $actions{$action}) {
    $actions{$action}->(@ARGV);
}
else {
    die "Unknown action: $action. Choose one of:\n\t",
        join("\n\t", keys %actions),
        "\n";
}
```

With this approach we just pass the remaining elements in `@ARGV` to the anonymous sub associated with the `Create_table` action, or die if we cannot find a matching action.

Now what we have to look at is what needs to happen inside of our action's subroutine.  The elements that we pass in come from `@ARGV` and will be:

```
($filename, $tablename, @content)
```

So we grab those arguments:

```
my ($fname, $tname, @content) = @_;
```

Then we need to open the output file in append mode.  Append mode is specified using the `'>>'` designation:

```
open my $out_fh, '>>', $fname
    or die "Error opening $fname for append: $!\n";
```

That last bit is some error handling: If the file cannot be opened we've reached an exceptional state that cannot be easily recovered from at this point in the script, so we throw an exception (die) and exit with an appropriate message sent to STDERR.

Next we will append some text to our output file. First we append the table name, and then we print the remaining items from `@ARGV` (the `@content` at this point), by joining each "word" together with `' | '`:

```
print $out_fh "$tname\n", join(' | ', @content), "\n";
```

Finally we close the filehandle explicitly to make it possible to detect errors:

```
close $out_fh or die "Error writing to $fname: $!\n";
```

You may have noticed `$!` a couple of times now.  In Perl, if a system call (such as `open`, `close`, and many others) fails, the special variable `$!` will contain the error message in string context, so appending it to our error output will provide some diagnostic information to the caller.

Putting it all together we get this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %actions = (
    Create_table => sub {
        my ($fname, $tname, @content) = @_;

        open my $out_fh, '>>', $fname
            or die "Could not complete action Create_table - Failed to open $fname for append: $!\n";

        print $out_fh "$tname\n", join(' | ', @content), "\n";
        close $out_fh or die "Error writing to $fname: $!\n";
    },
);

my $action = shift @ARGV;

if (exists $actions{$action}) {
    $actions{$action}->(@ARGV);
}
else {
    die "Unknown action: $action\n";
}
```

Additional action handling could easily be added by populating more `ACTION_NAME => sub {...},` elements into the `%actions` hash.

If your command line processing needs to be more elaborate, see `Getopt::Long`, which ships with Perl.

For additional documentation describing the constructs used in this example code see:

- `perldoc perlintro`: A quick introduction to Perl.
- `perldoc perlopentut`, `perldoc -f open`, `perldoc -f close`: File handling.
- `perldoc perlvar`: Explanation of `$!` and `@ARGV`.
- `perldoc -f join`
- `perldoc -f die`: Error handling.
- `perldoc perldata`: Explanation of hashes.
- `perldoc perlreftut`: Explanation of references (including subrefs)
- `perldoc perlsyn`: Explanation of the `if(){}` syntax.
- `perldoc perlsub`: Explanation of subroutines, parameter passing, and anonymous subs.

Perl's documentation is available on the command line as:

```
perldoc [-f] DOCUMENT_NAME
```

where `-f` is used to specify individual functions or subroutines rather than broader-scoped documents.

If you are new to Perl, start with `perldoc perlintro` and build from there.